# How we can implement SSL in Drupal pages?

Tags: drupal, ssl

How we can implement SSL in Drupal pages? I mean secure pages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the module SecurePages. It lets you enter URLs or paths that should be secure. If you are using Ubercart, you may want to look at UbercartSSL instead.

http://www.drupal.org/project/securepages

http://drupal.org/project/uc_ssl

Comment: +1 - This module is very simple to install and use, though obviously you need your SSL certificate up and running before you activate it...